# entity framework migration (azure): appyling migration fails with: Error: DefaultConnection is not set

Tags: azure, entity-framework

I am trying to migrate my azure db and add another table to it.
Everything seems to be working fine until I apply the migration to the db: i get this:

[image]

I adds a migration .cs class into my migrations folder but upon appyling the migration it fails with "default connection is not set".

This is my context:

```
namespace SkillbasedMiddleware.Db
{
    public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MigrationDbContext>
    {
        public MigrationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();
            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MigrationDbContext>();
            var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("C10");
            builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
            return new MigrationDbContext(builder.Options);
        }
    }
    public partial class MigrationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MigrationDbContext()
        {
        }

        public MigrationDbContext(DbContextOptions<MigrationDbContext> options): base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<UserItem> User => Set<UserItem>();
        public DbSet<UserDetailItem> UserDetail => Set<UserDetailItem>();
        public DbSet<TestItem> TestDb => Set<TestItem>();

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserItem>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.Email).IsRequired();
                entity.Property(e => e.Password).IsRequired();

                entity.Property(e => e.Version)
                    .IsRowVersion()
                    .IsConcurrencyToken();
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<UserDetailItem>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.Version)
                    .IsRowVersion()
                    .IsConcurrencyToken();
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<TestItem>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.Email).IsRequired();

                entity.Property(e => e.Version)
                    .IsRowVersion()
                    .IsConcurrencyToken();
            });


            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
```

I am wondering why it reads from appsettings.json, where it just states this:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

.. which doesnt apply as my db is hosted on azure, not locally. Maybe the issue is here?
But even then, the default connection is set.
Can you help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

- Here I was able to migrate a database to Azure hosted SQL server by adding a `ConnectionStrings` tab in the app settings and add the connection string to that tab.

My `appsettings.json`

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MVCDemoConnectionString": "<YOU CAN ADD YOU CONNECTION STRING HERE >"
  }
}
```

`MVCDemoConnectionString` will be name of the connection string .

- now in the `program.cs` I add the following configuration which will connect the dbcontext class and connection string

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MVCDemoDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration
        .GetConnectionString("MVCDemoConnectionString")
    )
);
```

output after migration :

[image]